# Parse values from rows into new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing, dplyr

I have a big data frame in R (> 250k rows). There is a column `land_use` which has different values (%) and land use categories:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), land_use = c("Parks/Open Space 100%", 
                                            "Single-Family 100%", 
                                            "Educational 26%  Vacant 74%", 
                                            "Educational 50 % Retail 50%", 
                                            "Undevelopable 50% Mobile Homes 50%",
                                            "Retail 100%" , 
                                            "Single-Family 12%  Vacant 88%", 
                                            "Single-Family 71% Agriculture 29%", 
                                            "Single-Family 10% Agriculture 20% Vacant 30% Parks/Open Space 40%",
                                            "Parks/Open Space 40% Single-Family 60%"))
```

In the end, I'll need to append each unique category as a separate column and insert the adjacent value in that specific column:

```
new_df = structure(list(id = 1:10, land_use = c("Parks/Open Space 100%", 
"Single-Family 100%", "Educational 26%  Vacant 74%", "Educational 50 % Retail 50%", 
"Undevelopable 50% Mobile Homes 50%", "Retail 100%", "Single-Family 12%  Vacant 88%", 
"Single-Family 71% Agriculture 29%", "Single-Family 10% Agriculture 20% Vacant 30% Parks/Open Space 40%", 
"Parks/Open Space 40% Single-Family 60%"), `Parks/Open Space` = c(100, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40, 40), `Single-Family` = c(NA, 
100, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12, 71, 10, 60), Educational = c(NA, NA, 
26, 50, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Vacant = c(NA, NA, 74, NA, NA, 
NA, 88, NA, 30, NA), Undevelopable = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 50, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Retail = c(NA, NA, NA, 50, NA, 100, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Agriculture = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29, 20, 
NA), `Mobile Homes` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 50, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

As approach, I was thinking to create the unique categories, insert new columns based on those and try a loop to populate each column. For the beginning:

```
categories <- gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', df$land_use) # remove the numeric values first
categories_split <- strsplit(x = categories, split = '%') # split using the '%' sign
categories_split <- unique(unlist(categories_split)) # there will be some extra-spaces in the column names after that
```

However, looping through 260 k rows will be slower than wanted so I am wondering if someone more experienced will find a better/simpler solution (like a vectorized function or dplyr).

Thanks!

Comment: I strongly urge you *not* to take this approach.  It makes your data frame untidy.  Instead, I'd create a a data frame with (say) columns  `ID`, `Category`, and `Usage`.  I'm am confident that this structure will make your subsequent processing easier than your suggestion, whatever that might entail.

Comment: How many unique categories do you have?

Comment: @Julian I think somewhere around 20 after the data cleaning. But I am not sure, I am hoping to get the unique categories first and clean the data after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a temporary column, `name`, equal to `land_use` and separate it into rows filtering out empty junk.  Then separate each element of `name` and convert to wide form. Note that `pivot_wider` uses `name` and `value` as the default values for `names_from` and `values_from` arguments.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(name = land_use) %>%
  separate_rows(name, sep = " *% *") %>%
  filter(name != "") %>%
  separate(name, c("name", "value"), sep = " (?=\\d)") %>%
  pivot_wider
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 10
      id land_use  Parks…¹ Singl…² Educa…³ Vacant Retail Undev…⁴ Mobil…⁵ Agric…⁶
   <int> <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1     1 Parks/Op… 100     <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
 2     2 Single-F… <NA>    100     <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
 3     3 Educatio… <NA>    <NA>    26      74     <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
 4     4 Educatio… <NA>    <NA>    50      <NA>   50     <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
 5     5 Undevelo… <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   50      50      <NA>   
 6     6 Retail 1… <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   100    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
 7     7 Single-F… <NA>    12      <NA>    88     <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
 8     8 Single-F… <NA>    71      <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    29     
 9     9 Single-F… 40      10      <NA>    30     <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    20     
10    10 Parks/Op… 40      60      <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​`Parks/Open Space`, ²​`Single-Family`,
#   ³​Educational, ⁴​Undevelopable, ⁵​`Mobile Homes`, ⁶​Agriculture
```

Answer (score 3):

First separate multiple entries per id with `tidyr::separate_rows()`, then separate the category from the percentage using `tidyr::separate()`, then use `readr::parse_number()` to coerce the percentage to numeric:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_new1 <- df %>%
  # first fix values with extra space before "%"
  mutate(land_use = str_remove(land_use, "\\s+(?=%)")) %>%
  separate_rows(land_use, sep = "(?<=%)\\s+") %>%
  separate(land_use, into = c("land_use", "pct"), sep = "\\s+(?=\\d+%$)") %>%
  mutate(pct = parse_number(pct))
```

This gives you this nice tidy dataframe, which as @Limey commented may be easier to work with:

```
#> df_new1
# A tibble: 19 × 3
      id land_use           pct
   <int> <chr>            <dbl>
 1     1 Parks/Open Space   100
 2     2 Single-Family      100
 3     3 Educational         26
 4     3 Vacant              74
 5     4 Educational         50
 6     4 Retail              50
 7     5 Undevelopable       50
 8     5 Mobile Homes        50
 9     6 Retail             100
10     7 Single-Family       12
11     7 Vacant              88
12     8 Single-Family       71
13     8 Agriculture         29
14     9 Single-Family       10
15     9 Agriculture         20
16     9 Vacant              30
17     9 Parks/Open Space    40
18    10 Parks/Open Space    40
19    10 Single-Family       60
```

However, if you do want your land use columns, it’s just one more step to `tidyr::pivot_wider()`:

```
df_new2 <- df_new1 %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = land_use, values_from = pct)
```

```
#> df_new2
# A tibble: 10 × 9
      id `Parks/Open Space` `Single-Family` Educational Vacant Retail
   <int>              <dbl>           <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1                100              NA          NA     NA     NA
 2     2                 NA             100          NA     NA     NA
 3     3                 NA              NA          26     74     NA
 4     4                 NA              NA          50     NA     50
 5     5                 NA              NA          NA     NA     NA
 6     6                 NA              NA          NA     NA    100
 7     7                 NA              12          NA     88     NA
 8     8                 NA              71          NA     NA     NA
 9     9                 40              10          NA     30     NA
10    10                 40              60          NA     NA     NA
# ℹ 3 more variables: Undevelopable <dbl>, `Mobile Homes` <dbl>,
#   Agriculture <dbl>
```

You can set unobserved categories to `0` instead of `NA` by setting `values_fill = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

as @Limey proposes, keeping your data [tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) will help you in most cases. You could do like so:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  ## replace the last blank with arbitrary separator (here: ;)
  mutate(land_use = land_use |> gsub(pattern = '(^.*) ', replacement = '\\1;')) |>
  separate(land_use,
           into = c('cat', 'val'),
           sep = ';'
           )
```

truncated output:

```
   id                                                           cat  val
1   1                                              Parks/Open Space 100%
2   2                                                 Single-Family 100%
3   3                                       Educational 26%  Vacant  74%
4   4                                       Educational 50 % Retail  50%
```

If you actually have fixed width columns, check out `separate_wider_delim` of the newest {tidyr} version.

However, if you do need *one hot encoding* (one column per feature category), see e.g. [this overview](https://www.statology.org/one-hot-encoding-in-r/) on statology.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips, those are very useful. I'm also in the favor of using the long than the wide format but I had to comply with a client's desire in this instance.